# Rails[RSpec]: put :update, no route matches :id => nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, routes

Very strange error. I am writing RSpec tests for a `subgroup` controller, which is in a many-to-one relationship with `group`. `group` accepts nested attributes for `subgroup`. I used scaffolding, and I've used the tests provided (edited to test). These tests were all working before I started testing for Devise. Now, my tests for updating with invalid parameters are failing.

tests in subgroups_controller_spec.rb

```
let(:invalid_attributes) {
  {name: nil, group_id: nil}
}

context "with invalid params" do
  it "assigns the subgroup as @subgroup" do
    subgroup = Subgroup.create! valid_attributes
    puts "param: #{subgroup.to_param}, id: #{subgroup.id}
    put :update, {:id => subgroup.to_param, :subgroup => invalid_attributes}, valid_session
    expect(assigns(:subgroup)).to eq(subgroup)
  end

  it "re-renders the 'edit' template" do
    subgroup = Subgroup.create! valid_attributes
    put :update, {:id => subgroup.to_param, :subgroup => invalid_attributes}, valid_session
    expect(response).to render_template("edit")
  end
end
```

error message:

```
1) SubgroupsController PUT #update with invalid params assigns the subgroup as @subgroup
     Failure/Error: put :update, {:id => subgroup.to_param, :subgroup => invalid_attributes}, valid_session
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups", :id=>nil, :locale=>nil}
```

But `puts "param: #{subgroup.to_param}, id: #{subgroup.id}"` prints `param: 1, id: 1` so clearly these ids are not nil.

rake routes:

```
    subgroups GET      (/:locale)/subgroups(.:format)           subgroups#index 
              POST     (/:locale)/subgroups(.:format)           subgroups#create 
 new_subgroup GET      (/:locale)/subgroups/new(.:format)       subgroups#new 
edit_subgroup GET      (/:locale)/subgroups/:id/edit(.:format)  subgroups#edit
     subgroup GET      (/:locale)/subgroups/:id(.:format)       subgroups#show
              PATCH    (/:locale)/subgroups/:id(.:format)       subgroups#update
              PUT      (/:locale)/subgroups/:id(.:format)       subgroups#update
              DELETE   (/:locale)/subgroups/:id(.:format)       subgroups#destroy
```

p.s. there are locales listed in the routes but I removed them for easier viewing. I don't think locales is this issue as update needs an :id to update.

Comment: I tried `put :update, {:id => 1, :subgroup => invalid_attributes}, valid_session` and it still comes up as `:id=>nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your `put` route, with the in the rendering that it's doing. You're getting a template error and the error specifics show that you're trying to do a `show` on `groups`. Check your layout for paths that are used.

Comment: I'm so silly, I didn't read the error carefully at all. That's right, the invalid params include nil for :group_id, and it started failing because I `render_views` to test Devise functionality. Just moved the `render_views` elsewhere... thank you!